# How to make User Objects for Universe Sandbox 2?

Tags: pc, macos, linux, universe-sandbox-2

I've looked all over the Internet for a tutorial, but came up with zero results.

**In the "Add" menu of Universe Sandbox 2, there is a button named "User Objects".**

This obviously means there is a way to add your own objects into the game. What I don't know however, is ***how*** to do this.
There is a tab next to it called "Objects" containing things like a Dice and a Baseball.

How would I go about making my own?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

After i played around and Finn Rayment did not get it to work, i just [**started a thread in the Steamcommunity**](http://steamcommunity.com/app/230290/discussions/0/618459109266177170/) about this and got the following answer from a developer

> You can't import external models yet. We'll hopefully add it at some point in the future though.

So my first answer is just for Universe Sanbox 1.

---

### First answer

I can't give you an answer for Universe Sandbox 2 but something similar was available in the first game.

You can add your own textures and even full 3d models, that's what "User Objects" were in the first game. I could explain everything in deep but that would be a lot of text and because of that i'll quote a Q/A of the Universe Sandbox Forum and [**leave you the link**.](http://universesandbox.com/forum/index.php?topic=3440.0)

> 1. what is a .dds file? how do I create some with my planetary textures? I have Photoshop and Corel draw... do I need another
>      software package?
>
> .dds is a DirectX image format, but you can use bmp, jpg, png, or tga
>   files too. No need to convert it to a .dds file.
>
> 2. I have 3ds max and Maya for 3d modeling, are these compatible software packages and if yes what file format do I need to export my
>      model(s) for sandbox to "see" them and import them? If these packages
>      are not compatible please recommend a software package that will allow
>      me to create models and import them into sandbox.
>
> Universe Sandbox supports the import of .x files (another DirectX
>   format) and .3ds (a standard 3D format).
>
> 3. If we hypothesize that one of the above software packages are compatible then is there a limit on what kind of models will Sandbox
>      recon? Do they have to be spheres for suns/planets or can I import i.e
>      a human being and set it on an orbit around Earth?
>
> Yes. You can import any type of 3D model that's in the correct format.
>   To get the correct scaling the model should be 2 units across, so a
>   custom sphere would have a radius of 1. There's room for improvement
>   in the scaling and size options in the interface.
>
> 4. Assuming I manage to import a model in Sandbox will sandbox allow me to start changing options or do I have to do something else before
>      I am allowed by the program to change any options?
>
> The model will import right away. Try typing 'dice' in the model box
>   to instantly load a dice model.
>
> 5. Is there a way inside Sandbox to create my own galaxies/stars/planets with or without textures ?
>
> You can create planets and stars, but the options for galaxies is
>   currently very limited. However there is yet no way to save the
>   created object to the icon bar.
>
> 6. Is there a way to get models and/or textures of galaxies, etc from scientific web sites like NASA, etc? If yes do you know of any such
>      web site url?
>
> Some of the textures and models from this site will be useful:
>   http://www.celestiamotherlode.net/

(The link in 6. is dead)

I hope this helps and good luck with the 3D-Modeling.

Comment: Thankyou for the information, I appreciate it. I will try this later as I am busy at this current given time. As for the moment, have you personally tried this yourself?

Comment: I've never tried in us2 just in the first game but with models i've downloaded. I've had never enough time to make my own models^^

Comment: Ok. Will have to have a go. :P

Comment: *sigh* I'm still running into problems, but your help deserved the bounty. :P Thanks.

Comment: The problem is, I "imported" a model of the Hubble Space Telescope in .3DS format, by putting it in **<user>/Documents/UniverseSandbox2/Bodies**, and now when I load up Universe Sandbox 2, it doesn't appear anyway. Any ideas?

Comment: Well i can't remember the folders where you've to import your models. However there was a problem with *.3ds files back in US1, try to save it as *x file (directX) that should work. edit: found this http://universesandbox.com/forum/index.php?topic=3644.0

Comment: Converted to .x, placed it in same folder. Opened game, nothing happened. Downloaded a .x off the Internet to be sure, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: i found http://universesandbox.com/forum/index.php?topic=5408.0 where someone said: `- Copy myModel.3ds in documents/universe sandbox/media folder
- Start game
- Add an planet
- focus planet
- go to pysical properties
- write myModel in model` maybe that helps?

Comment: Well it seems like you should forget everything i said for now. Here's a "What's new to US²" file and I can't find the "import" option for now https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TTsJL-ddM_i5RjfnQV5_R-hocRCin6hxAiCuVlytRtA/edit?pli=1# maybe it's not yet implemented!?

Comment: And i added the simple question to the Universe Sandbox discussion on Steam: http://steamcommunity.com/app/230290/discussions/0/611703709828255266/ i'll add any additional information here but you can of course keep an eye there too

Comment: Thanks alot. I really appreciate the help. As the Developer personally posted on your question, I will take that answer as a "no" you cannot. Accepted the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. As soon as importing models will become available(if it will be anytime) i'll insert this to my answer as an update